# php duplicate keys in an array for a dropdown list

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I need to show duplicate values from a mysql table in a dropdown list. 
I was not able to do this because arrays cannot have duplicate keys.
But I have found a function which can take duplicate keys.

I need someone's help who can guide me to put dropdown list values into this function:

dropdownlist:

```
$dc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ECR_CBDC WHERE Prod_desc='$product' AND Ac_code='$custcode' AND Ecr_No=0 AND usr='$user' AND Cylno!='' ORDER BY Cylno ASC");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($dc);
$fill_from_array = array(); /* as "value"=>"option" */
for($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($dc);
$fill_from_array[$row['Cylno']] = $row['Cylno'];
}
```

function to have duplicate keys:

```
<?php
function array_combine_($keys, $values)
{
$result = array();
foreach ($keys as $i => $k) {
$result[$k][] = $values[$i];
}
array_walk($result, create_function('&$v', '$v = (count($v) == 1)? array_pop($v): $v;'));
return    $result;
}

print_r(array_combine_(Array('2','2','3'), Array(2,2,3)));
?>
```

Table ECR_CBDC has following values for a column Cylno:
    10
    20
    20
    30
    40
    50
    50

When I put the above values into an array - fill_from_array, the values would be like this:

```
10 => 10 
20 => 20 
30 => 30 
40 => 40 
50 => 50
```

What I need in the array is :

```
10 => 10 
20 => 20 
20 => 20 
30 => 30 
40 => 40 
50 => 50 
50 => 50
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Voitcus       I will add the expected values in my question, so that it would be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using an other way

```
function array_combine($array, $key, $value)
{
     $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value);
     return $array;
}
```

or

```
function array_combine(Array $keys, Array $values)
{
    $array = [];
    foreach($keys as $i => $key)
    {
        $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $values[$i]);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

At the end your array could look like

```
0 => [key] 2 | [value] 2
1 => [key] 2 | [value] 2
2 => [key] 3 | [value] 3
```

When you do an select on the SQl it will return an array like

```
[0] => [[field_1] => 10, [field_2] => 20],
[1] => [[field_1] => 10, [field_2] => 20],
[2] => [[field_1] => 10, [field_2] => 20],
```

Then you could use a foreach

Method 1, uses first method of array_combine

```
$array = array(); // or [] for php 5.4+
foreach ( $results as $result)
{
    $array = array_combine($array, $result['field_1'], $result['field_2']);
}
```

To make the dropdown use the following function

```
function makeDropDown($array)
{
$options = '';
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $options .= '<option value="' . $value['key']  . '">' . $value['value']  . '</option>';
}
return $options;
}
```

You should use it like

```
<select><?php echo makeDropDown($array); ?></select>
```

Comment: Could you please give an example to insert the values into this function from MYSQL Table.

Comment: Added a small example at the end. But it is prety stright forward

Comment: I have done, please check code, it gives error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '.
$dc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ECR_CBDC WHERE Prod_desc='$product' AND Ac_code='$custcode' AND Ecr_No=0 AND usr='$user' AND Cylno!='' ORDER BY Cylno ASC");
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($dc);
 
 $results = mysql_fetch_array($dc);
 array_combine(Array $array, $key, $value)
 {
 $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => value);
     return $array;
 }

 $array = [];
 foreach ( $results as $result)
 {
  $array = array_combine($array, $result['Cylno'], $result['Cylno']
 }

Comment: Before array_combine missed the keyword function, also the example missed the ; Don't know for your query

Comment: Now it is giving syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line:  $array = [];

Comment: You probably have php 5.3 or lower, then you need to change that to array() (so $array = array()) from php 5.4 the [] became the short tag for arrays

Comment: Now there is another error after doing $array=array(); Error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare array_combine()

Comment: I have changed $array[] to $array() in function, but now it is giving error like: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line - $array() = array('key' => $key, 'value' => value);

Comment: As per my search on the internet, array_combine() works only on php5+ version, what i am using currently is php4.3.1, in such a case what should be used.

Comment: I changed the code in the answer so it should support php4, but I stronly recommend that you update to php 5.3+ (bug fixes, oo, faster and a lot more)

Comment: Sorry, error continues : Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line : $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => value);

Comment: My current code as per your response, FYI : function array_combine($array, $key, $value)
 {
     $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => value);
     return $array;
 }
  
 $array = array(); // or [] for php 5.4+
 foreach ( $results as $result)
 {
 $array = array_combine($array, $result['Cylno'], $result['Cylno'];
 }

Comment: Had some small errors in the code, sorry, function array_combine($array, $key, $value) 
{ 
 $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value); 
 return $array; 
} 

$array = array(); // or [] for php 5.4+ 
foreach ( $results as $result) 
{ 
 $array = array_combine($array, $result['Cylno'], $result['Cylno']); 
} should work

Comment: Now i am getting another error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare array_combine() on line function array_combine($array, $key, $value)

Comment: Should we remove $ sign from key and value in function ?

Comment: No you should not do that, the error means you have the function array_combine twice in your application, remove the others or rename one to make it work!

Comment: No, I have it defined only once, it is exactly the same as what you have given in the above flagged response and nothing else. kindly help, it still says cannot redeclare.

Comment: try function array_combine_epic($array, $key, $value) { $array[] = array('key' => $key, 'value' => $value); return $array; } $array = array(); // or [] for php 5.4+ foreach ( $results as $result) { $array = array_combine_epic($array, $result['Cylno'], $result['Cylno']); }

Comment: Finally there is no error, but dropdown list now has strange values and not the actual values. Values are like this: 0
(key)4
(value)4
1
(key)4
(value)4

Comment: thats because you need to reorder your dropdown maker, see example in answer

Comment: I think everything is fine, only the values are not getting displayed in the dropdown, I have done as per the new response: <select><?php echo makeDropDown($array); ?></select>

Comment: Yes, exactly like your answer. I think $options has an issue.

Comment: Nice one, forgot to return it

Comment: Now another issue, dropdown is showing duplicate value 17times, where as it has to show duplicate and other values along with it.

Answer (score 0):

just use your sql query to fetch duplicate records only.

```
SELECT * FROM ECR_CBDC WHERE Prod_desc='$product' AND Ac_code='$custcode' AND Ecr_No=0 AND usr='$user' AND Cylno!='' Having count(Cylno) > 1 ORDER BY Cylno ASC
```

Comment: Kindly see the output required, added later to the question.

Comment: @sridhars use primary key for index instead Cylno.

Comment: I think you got the question wrong, pl see once again, I am talking about an array with duplicate keys for a dropdownlist.